# macro to copy text from OOwriter cell

Tags: macros, copy, openoffice.org

I want to produce a sheet of labels, with each label copied 3 times

Adapting one of the label templates , i can produce a sheet with the label text reading from  a ODB file and producing text in the first column of cells in an OOWriter document  template

How do I copy the text from the first column of cells in OOWriter to cells in columns 2 and 3 ?  ive tried the record option to copy the cell and then copy the text , but it doesnt record anything.

IIRC a few years ago there was a business card  producing template that did something similar  - copied the contents of the first cell in OOwroter to the whole sheet , but i cant find it

Answer (score 0):

eventually did it by

- defined my own labels the width of the page

  added tabs at the point i wanted the 2nd & 3rd block of text to start
  (approx 6.4 and 12.8 cm)

  mailmerge  to add the fields

  copied the added fields to the tabbe positions